# Creating training data set for named entity recognition for job titles

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to recognise job titles from texts. How can I create a larger training data set by extending my small training data set?
Do some ready package or open projects for extend training set exist?

Answer (score 3):

There is an open set of ~44,000 job titles, and their corresponding standard job codes, published as part of O*Net (The US Dept. of Labor occupational data program). You can download the file here:

https://www.onetcenter.org/database.html#occ

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of request, you can send an email to the corpora mailing list :

http://www.hit.uib.no/corpora/welcome.html